# Modified file (.js, .css) not update changes

Tags: javascript, c#

Using visual studio 2015 everything working fine but the problem is, if I modify JavaScript or css file the changes does not build (shown). These files linked to .aspx file from their own folder.

Please anyone help me

Comment: Clean and build the project.

Comment: Thank you,  Tried this way but not working for web app (it working fine for window application)

Comment: Working JS with windows app ?

Comment: No, don’t mean that but I means for building and rebuilding

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to understand what do you mean by changes not being "built". Since there is nothing to build in .js or .css in Visual Studio itself.

If you are using something like webpack that does process these files you need to provide more examples.

But my bet you mean that they are not updated in the browser and you just need to make sure you disabled the cache when you loaded them.

E.g. in chrome:

[image]

You cannot use this approach of course with real users, so you need to think how you make sure the cache is busted. Most common approach is to add some version `?v=1.01` or the hash of the file as a parameter (either directly or inside a bundle which is better usually). You can google a bit more on that.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, but my issue is cahe because tried to run by using another browser working fine but still not working in the first browser

Comment: You need to add a way to bust the cache and the best approach is to use the hash of the contents, then you need not to worry about manually updating the versions. Just google a bit on how you can achieve that or ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the files are cached. Load the page and hit CTRL and F5 together, that should force a reload of all the resources.

If that's not working, make sure in the properties of the files, they are set to Content so this will copy them on build.

Answer (score 0):

Force the browser to load newer css or js files by appending an extra parameter

example

//new/newJavascript.js?k=1

just keep on updating value of k. This will force browser to load new file with changes.

or better press ctrl+f5

Comment: That's not the best way really, since you will have to update i manually all the time. Hash of the contents is more reliable.

Comment: yeah that will also do or else take a variable and change the value from web.config which will update all the file